# Angularjs - Is this the right time to use angular 4?

Tags: angular

Is this the right time to use Angular 4 for an enterprise SAP or we should stick to angular-2 and wait for a final release of angular-4? I have seen rapid releases of angular-4. (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Please suggest.

Comment: most of the changes are under the hood you can opt for it

Answer (score 1):

Angular 4 was finally released on the 23rd of March, so yes, this is the right time to use Angular 4 for an enterprise SAP. [Official Angular blog with announcement.](https://angularjs.blogspot.nl/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html)

As a matter of fact, Angular 4.1 [is available since April the 23rd](https://angularjs.blogspot.nl/2017/04/angular-410-now-available.html).